# io.elementary.code application name

Tags: code

First of all, I want to thank you guys for all your hard work. I really enjoy the consistency and fluidity of Elementary OS.
The custom basic applications follow those patterns nicely and they are well integrated.

The new text editor Code still named as io.elementary.code.
I assume that this will change since it is still in the beta to make CLI a lot easier, I was wondering what that name would be. Naming it simply code would conflict with Microsofts Visual Studio Code.
I hope that is something that is kept in mind due to VS Code being quite popular.

Thank you and keep up the good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name won't change.

> Further, we’re adopting RDNN across our apps. This is encouraged by FreeDesktop.Org projects like D-BUS as well as by GNOME, so we’re being consistent both with ourselves and other major Open Source projects.
>
> Moving forward, an elementary app with a generic name Baz would have a repository of github.com/elementary/baz, an app ID (including .desktop and AppData filenames) of io.elementary.baz, a binary of io.elementary.baz, and a gsettings path of /io/elementary/baz. User-facing, we’ll continue to refer to apps by their generic names (just “Baz”) as well.

See https://medium.com/elementaryos/cleaning-up-app-codenames-ef9fc637ddef#044c